# Add banner after ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have looked at almost every solution I could find about this but I can't get my code to work. I wan't to put a banner after 3 ng-repeats

```
<div class="row products-row" ng-init="onInit()">
  <div class="col col-34 fashion-product-container" ng-repeat="product in results = fashionProducts | FashionFilter:params | orderBy:sortby_obj.propertyName:sortby_obj.reverse as fashionResults">
    <div class="list card">
      <div class="item item-image product-image-wrapper">
          <pre-img ratio="_3_4">
            <img class="product-image" ng-src="{{ product.image }}" spinner-on-load>
          </pre-img>
      </div>
      <div class="item item-body product-description-wrapper">
        <h5 class="product-title">
            {{ product.name }}
        </h5>
        <p class="product-description">
          <b class="actual-price bold-price">${{product.price_sale}}</b>
          <span class="previous-price bold-price" ng-show="product.price != '0'">${{product.price}}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12" id="Banner" ng-if="$index==3">Banner</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$index`

like

`<div id="banner" ng-show="$index == 3"></div>`

Now this will show banner div when its the third element of ng-repeat.

Your `<div class="col-md-12" id="Banner" ng-if="$index==3">Banner</div>` is outside of `<div>` containing `ng-repeat` tag. due to that `$index` is undefined.

Just put it inside the div of ng-repeat and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<div class="row products-row" ng-init="onInit()">
  <div ng-repeat="product in results = fashionProducts | FashionFilter:params | orderBy:sortby_obj.propertyName:sortby_obj.reverse as fashionResults">
    <div class="col col-34 fashion-product-container">
      <div class="list card">
        <div class="item item-image product-image-wrapper">
            <pre-img ratio="_3_4">
              <img class="product-image" ng-src="{{ product.image }}" spinner-on-load>
            </pre-img>
        </div>
        <div class="item item-body product-description-wrapper">
          <h5 class="product-title">
              {{ product.name }}
          </h5>
          <p class="product-description">
            <b class="actual-price bold-price">${{product.price_sale}}</b>
            <span class="previous-price bold-price" ng-show="product.price != '0'">${{product.price}}</span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" id="Banner" ng-show="$index==3">Banner</div>
  </div>
</div>
```